# Flutter call back url

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm using a dependency to implement a payment system in my flutter app using Paystack Payment system. This is the dependency [pay_with_paystak](https://pub.dev/packages/pay_with_paystack)

In the dependency it's expecting me to provide a `callbackUrl`. What is this `callbackUrl` and how do I create one for both Android and iOS?

```
PayWithPayStack().now(
    secretKey:
    "sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    customerEmail: "popekabu@gmail.com",
    reference:
    DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
    callbackUrl: "setup in your paystack dashboard"//How do I do this?
    currency: "GHS",
    paymentChannel:["mobile_money", "card"],
    amount: "20000",
    transactionCompleted: () {
        print("Transaction Successful");
    },
    transactionNotCompleted: () {
        print("Transaction Not Successful!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/pay_with_paystack#definitions) explains it:

> callbackUrl URL to redirect to after payment is successful, this helps close the session. This is setup in the Dashboard of paystack and the same URL setup is then provided here by you again.

Having said that, [their example](https://pub.dev/packages/pay_with_paystack/example) doesn't have one so it's probably optional. I don't have access to a dashboard to verify this.

```
PayWithPayStack().now(
    context: context,
    secretKey:
    "sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    customerEmail: "popekabu@gmail.com",
    reference: DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
    currency: "GHS",
    amount: "20000",
    transactionCompleted: () {
        print("Transaction Successful");
    },
    transactionNotCompleted: () {
        print("Transaction Not Successful!");
    });
```

Comment: That's the problem. They don't have an example of it and I don't if that's the reason why the transactionCompleted and the transactionNotCompleted functions are working. It doesn't print anything even after the transaction has been completed. The transaction works very well though. Maybe you can help with that?

Comment: why don't you test it by adding some dummy url in and seeing what happens? If you're building a mobile app, then perhaps a deeplink would be the way to go. See what happens with www.google.com first.

Answer (score 0):

[Pay_with_paystack](https://pub.dev/packages/pay_with_paystack) uses WebView internally.

So CallbackURL denotes, After the successful transaction where you want to redirect. This helps PayStack to close the session. If you want to have this sort of functionality in Flutter you might have to set up a URL that redirects to your Flutter Screen, which I won't recommend.

#### 2 Good Ways to Solve this Issue

1. [Displaying Checkout in Your WebView](https://paystack.com/docs/guides/using_the_paystack_checkout_in_a_mobile_webview/#displaying-checkout-in-your-webview) - Here they used Webview to work with PayStack

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://checkout.paystack.com/7zu1ot06d0qn9h6',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      userAgent: 'Flutter;Webview',
    ),
  );
}
```

2. Use [Flutter_PayStack](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack) instead.
   People are using it day in and day out and it works nicely.

- To achieve redirect after the successful transaction you may use `pushAndRemoveUntil`.

```dart
// Just for reference
 CheckoutResponse response = await plugin.checkout(
      context,
      method: CheckoutMethod.card,
      charge: charge,
    );

    if (response.status == true) {
      message = 'Payment was successful. Ref: ${response.reference}';
      if (mounted) {}
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SuccessScreen(message: message)),
          ModalRoute.withName('/'));
    } else {
      print(response.message);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much but while this seems a viable solution, it doesn't have the payment method I want to implement (That is "the mobile_money payment system"). It was the first dependency that came to mind but most people in the country I'm building this app for use the mobile_mobile and unless they have it I don't think it will be useful to me.

Comment: With the first method you suggested, do I implement it in the transactionCompleted or what? I've read the doc but I don't know how to implement it